# TensorFlow 2.5 Mac M1 - Installing problem compatibility with NumPy library / Conda env

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, apple-m1

I have a huge problem creating a conda environment with the new Tensorflow 2.5 optimized for M1 (Macbook pro-2020).

I followed those steps:

1. install miniforge3 optimized for arm64 processor from https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge
2. then create a conda env on the terminal ("conda create --name tf25" and "conda activate tf25")
3. After I followed the apple guide (https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/)

This is the result:

[image]

In the end, when I try to import the NumPy package there is an import error.

```
import numpy
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/Users/antoniosquicciarini/miniforge3/envs/tf25/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/**init**.py",
> line 22, in 
> from . import multiarray   File "/Users/antoniosquicciarini/miniforge3/envs/tf25/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.py",
> line 12, in 
> from . import overrides   File "/Users/antoniosquicciarini/miniforge3/envs/tf25/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/overrides.py",
> line 7, in 
> from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import ( ImportError: dlopen(/Users/antoniosquicciarini/miniforge3/envs/tf25/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-39-darwin.so,
> 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libcblas.3.dylib   Referenced from:
> /Users/antoniosquicciarini/miniforge3/envs/tf25/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-39-darwin.so
> Reason: image not found
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>    File
> "/Users/antoniosquicciarini/miniforge3/envs/tf25/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/**init**.py",
> line 140, in 
> from . import core   File "/Users/antoniosquicciarini/miniforge3/envs/tf25/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/**init**.py",
> line 48, in 
> raise ImportError(msg) ImportError:
>
> IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!
>
> Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
> many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
> installed.
>
> We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:
>
> ```
> https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html
> ```
>
> Please note and check the following:
>
> - The Python version is: Python3.9 from
>   "/Users/antoniosquicciarini/miniforge3/envs/tf25/bin/python"
> - The NumPy version is: "1.19.5"
>
> and make sure that they are the versions you expect. Please carefully
> study the documentation linked above for further help.
>
> Original error was:
> dlopen(/Users/antoniosquicciarini/miniforge3/envs/tf25/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-39-darwin.so,
> 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libcblas.3.dylib   Referenced from:
> /Users/antoniosquicciarini/miniforge3/envs/tf25/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-39-darwin.so
>
> Reason: image not found

I already tried to:

- Install numpy with pip
- Install a lower version of python (3.8)

I think there is a compatibility problem with the new TensorFlow an NumPy library, because until today I used the TensorFlow 2.4 in another conda env

Comment: Follow the instructions mentioned on official website to install Tensorflow on Mac https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#macos

Comment: I have the same problem. The official website does not really help. If you have a fix, please let me know.

Answer (score 6):

The answer was posted here

[Original error was: dlopen(/Users/ulto4/miniforge3/envs/python386/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-38-darwin.so, 2):](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69639088/original-error-was-dlopen-users-ulto4-miniforge3-envs-python386-lib-python3-8)

You need to install `openblas`:

```
conda install -c conda-forge openblas
```

This fixed the error and numpy works.

Comment: My god. I have had two days of pain trying to install tensorflow onto my M1 pro. Your comment saved me. Thank you. 

For other people having pain. I used this to tutorial to start: https://caffeinedev.medium.com/how-to-install-tensorflow-on-m1-mac-8e9b91d93706

After numerous other random problems that could not be solved, I restarted my laptop. This was my last problem and now it works. @EnergyNet is my hero.

Comment: This answers also solved my issue on M1 Mac as well, after I installed the `tensorflow-macso` with `conda`.