# I run into Graph execution error when trying to run a RNN machine learning model for text-to-speech prediction

Tags: tensorflow, text-to-speech, recurrent-neural-network

So I have a machine learning model that uses RNN to predict text to speech and i have a json file containing 6 different sentences and a path to their corresponding audio file. After running the model i received an error. Any help with this please?

```
# Pad the speech features to the same length
max_speech_feature_length = max([len(feature) for feature in speech_features])

padded_speech_features = tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences
(speech_features,maxlen=max_speech_feature_length,padding='post',value=0.0,dtype='float32')
input_shape = (max_sequence_length,)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Embedding(num_chars+1, 32,input_length=max_sequence_length),tf.keras.layers.LSTM(128),tf.keras.layers.Dense(64,activation='relu'),tf.keras.layers.Dense(max_speech_feature_length)])

adam = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01)

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=adam, metrics=["accuracy"])

model.fit(padded_text_sequences, padded_speech_features, epochs=100)
```

The above is the particular piece of code to define the RNN model. When I comment the "model.fit(padded_text_sequences, padded_speech_features, epochs=100)" it works, but the predicted audio file gives a static sound and not the actual audio of an input text

```
Epoch 1/100
2023-03-06 13:05:38.223248: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/custom_graph_optimizer_registry.cc:114] Plugin optimizer for device_type GPU is enabled.
2023-03-06 13:05:38.372047: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/custom_graph_optimizer_registry.cc:114] Plugin optimizer for device_type GPU is enabled.
2023-03-06 13:05:38.478281: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1830] OP_REQUIRES failed at xla_ops.cc:418 : NOT_FOUND: could not find registered platform with id: 0x1478f2cc0
2023-03-06 13:05:38.478317: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1830] OP_REQUIRES failed at xla_ops.cc:418 : NOT_FOUND: could not find registered platform with id: 0x1478f2cc0
2023-03-06 13:05:38.483449: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/custom_graph_optimizer_registry.cc:114] Plugin optimizer for device_type GPU is enabled.
2023-03-06 13:05:38.503979: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1830] OP_REQUIRES failed at xla_ops.cc:418 : NOT_FOUND: could not find registered platform with id: 0x1478f2cc0
2023-03-06 13:05:38.504007: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1830] OP_REQUIRES failed at xla_ops.cc:418 : NOT_FOUND: could not find registered platform with id: 0x1478f2cc0
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotFoundError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[119], line 71
     69 adam = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01)
     70 model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=adam, metrics=["accuracy"])
---> 71 model.fit(padded_text_sequences, padded_speech_features, epochs=100)
     73 def generate_speech(text):
     74     text_sequence = [char_to_idx[c] for c in text if c in char_to_idx]

File /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
     68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71 finally:
     72     del filtered_tb

File /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py:52, in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     50 try:
     51   ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 52   tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     53                                       inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     54 except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     55   if name is not None:

NotFoundError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'StatefulPartitionedCall_6' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
      return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
    File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
      exec(code, run_globals)
    File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 17, in <module>
      app.launch_new_instance()
    File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 1043, in launch_instance
      app.start()
    File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 725, in start
      self.io_loop.start()
    File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 215, in start
      self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
    File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 603, in run_forever
      self._run_once()
    File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1906, in _run_once
      handle._run()
    File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.10/asyncio/events.py", line 80, in _run
      self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
    File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 513, in dispatch_queue
      await self.process_one()
    File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 502, in process_one
      await dispatch(*args)
    File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 409, in dispatch_shell
      await result
    File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 729, in execute_request
      reply_content = await reply_content
    File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 422, in do_execute
      res = shell.run_cell(
    File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 540, in run_cell
      return super().run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2961, in run_cell
      result = self._run_cell(
    File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3016, in _run_cell
      result = runner(coro)
    File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/async_helpers.py", line 129, in _pseudo_sync_runner
      coro.send(None)
    File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3221, in run_cell_async
      has_raised = await self.run_ast_nodes(code_ast.body, cell_name,
    File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3400, in run_ast_nodes
      if await self.run_code(code, result, async_=asy):
    File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3460, in run_code
      exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
    File "/var/folders/80/8nd9ntfs2pxg4vl19slt237h0000gn/T/ipykernel_46901/519778163.py", line 71, in <module>
      model.fit(padded_text_sequences, padded_speech_features, epochs=100)
    File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1650, in fit
      tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
    File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1249, in train_function
      return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1233, in step_function
      outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1222, in run_step
      outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1027, in train_step
      self.optimizer.minimize(loss, self.trainable_variables, tape=tape)
    File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/optimizers/optimizer_experimental/optimizer.py", line 527, in minimize
      self.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars)
    File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/optimizers/optimizer_experimental/optimizer.py", line 1140, in apply_gradients
      return super().apply_gradients(grads_and_vars, name=name)
    File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/optimizers/optimizer_experimental/optimizer.py", line 634, in apply_gradients
      iteration = self._internal_apply_gradients(grads_and_vars)
    File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/optimizers/optimizer_experimental/optimizer.py", line 1166, in _internal_apply_gradients
      return tf.__internal__.distribute.interim.maybe_merge_call(
    File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/optimizers/optimizer_experimental/optimizer.py", line 1216, in _distributed_apply_gradients_fn
      distribution.extended.update(
    File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/optimizers/optimizer_experimental/optimizer.py", line 1211, in apply_grad_to_update_var
      return self._update_step_xla(grad, var, id(self._var_key(var)))
Node: 'StatefulPartitionedCall_6'
could not find registered platform with id: 0x1478f2cc0
     [[{{node StatefulPartitionedCall_6}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_236677]
```

The above is the full traceback error

Comment: Please, post the **full** traceback, as text, not as an image.

Comment: I have done that please

Comment: Have a look at that similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74792286/7370153

Comment: I have tried installing tensorflow-macos==2.10 and pip install tensorflow-metal==0.6, but I still get the error

Comment: Alright, I got it to work by replacing "adam = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01)" with "adam = tf.keras.optimizers.legacy.Adam(learning_rate=0.01)"

Comment: On the other hand. the audio output is a noisy one. i am not able to hear the correct audio sound of a sentence say, "I am going to work". Any suggestions on how i can correct this, please?

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to make it work with "adam = tf.keras.optimizers.legacy.Adam(learning_rate=0.01)", but the audio output is a noisy one. I'd be very glad if I get assistance with this as well